# Entity Framework Core DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync() returns -1 as "rowsAffected" return value. What does this mean?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

When I call a stored procedure in MSQL Server using Entity Framework Core, I get a return value of -1. This is the number of affected rows.

First of all, this is wrong as my stored procedure deletes multiple entries from a table. What is even more strange to me is that the value is negative. Usually I'd assume this indicates an error, but my stored procedure is executed and the data is changed as expected.

Here's my C# code:

```cs
var rowsAffected = await this.dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("dbo.sp_DeleteSomeStuff").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The stored procedure looks like this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_DeleteSomeStuff
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        DECLARE @result int;
        EXEC @result = sp_getapplock @Resource = 'DeleteSomeStuffLock',
                                     @LockOwner='Transaction',
                                     @LockMode = 'Exclusive';

        -- result code 0 or 1 = success (error codes are negative)
        IF @result >= 0
        BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

            DELETE FROM [dbo].[MyTable] 
            WHERE [Expiration] < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END;

        RETURN @result;
END
GO
```

What does the -1 mean? And is there a way to get the actual count of affected rows from my stored procedure?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the `SET NOCOUNT ON;` statement prevented the affected rows to be counted. Removing this statement from the stored procedure fixed the problem.

Comment: The comment explained it, but didn't say you should necessarily set nocount on. I'd rather rely on [@@ROWCOUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score -1):

Removing `SET NOCOUNT ON` solves the -1 issue and it returns the correct no of row affected.

But not sure if it is better to remove `SET NOCOUNT ON`, or `return @@ROWCOUNT` as output from stored procedure.